# Nested permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I would like to compute all "nested permutations" (not sure if it's the right term) of a list consisting of *simple elements* (numbers, strings) and *simple sublists* (level 1 lists of *simple elements*).

For example, with the list `{1, {2, 3}}`, I calculate the nested permutations like this:

```
list = {1, {2, 3}};
Flatten[# /. ({a___, b_List, c___} :> ({a, #, c} & /@ b)) & /@ 
  Permutations[list], 1]
```

> ```
> {1,2}
> {1,3}
> {2,1}
> {3,1}
> ```

As you can see, I want all possible permutations where only one of the elements in the *simple sublists* is included. However, my method fails if the list contains more than one *simple sublist*:

```
list2 = {1, {2, 3}, {4}}
Flatten[# /. ({a___, b_List, c___} :> ({a, #, c} & /@ b)) & /@ 
  Permutations[list2], 1]
```

> ```
> {1,2,{4}}
> {1,3,{4}}
> {1,4,{2,3}}
> {2,1,{4}}
> {3,1,{4}}
> {2,{4},1}
> {3,{4},1}
> {4,1,{2,3}}
> {4,{2,3},1}
> ```

I tried replacing `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) with `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`), this however caused an infinite recursion:

> ```
> ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after {1,{2,3},{4}} scanned 65536 times. >>
> ```

How can I compute all possible permutations where only one element from each of the *simple sublists* is included?

Edit: there can be any number of *simple elements* and *simple lists* in a list, but there will never be any duplicates.

Comment: Can there be multiple simple elements? And if there are duplicate elements overall and selection/permutation results in a duplicate permutation, is it to remain or do you require distinctness? You need to better specify the question...

Comment: Yes, there can be any number of simple elements and simple lists. There can be no duplicate elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perms[l_] := Flatten[Permutations /@ Tuples[Replace[l, (x_Integer | x_String) -> {x}, {1}]], 1]
```

outputs

```
{{1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 2},
 {4, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3}, {3, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1},
 {4, 1, 3}, {4, 3, 1}}
```

when given input `{1, {2, 3}, {4}}`.

That is, if you just wrap each simple element in a `List` head, then use `Tuples` and find the permutations of each tuple thereby found, you get what I think you want.

Comment: Done. charactercharacter

Comment: Why did you edit your answer? Now it's less general as it only works if _simple elements_ are integers.

Comment: The fix is trivial. Someone said it would be better to write the function rather than just to demonstrate its application, so I did. I've made the obvious fix.

Comment: Doesn't work: `Tuples::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position {1,1} in Tuples[{1,{2,3},{4}}]. >>`

Comment: I must have been asleep, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Even better with `x_?(Head[#] =!= List &) -> {x}`.

Comment: @shrx I'd use a "skip rule" like `{x_List :> x, x_ :> {x}}`, or `Except`: `x : Except[_List] :> {x}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Outer`...

```
p[list_List] :=
   Flatten[Permutations /@
      Partition[
         Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ (list /. x_Integer -> {x})]], 
      Length[list]],
   1]
```